# Invoicing Visual Basic software replacement or web application?

Tags: software-recommendation, wine, application-development, gambas3

I have a pc that is still fairly powerful but with Windows XP (Pentium 4 3Ghz 4 Gb Ram).

It is used by someone who is not computer expert (I would say a really basic user) only for browsing and printing invoices.

The invoicing software is something that I developed like 10 years ago in Visual Basic, it is simple and functional and still running well.

This VB software is only the reason why I still keep XP in this computer, I would like to get rid of it and switch to Ubuntu latest release.

From what I have read here, the solutions are:

- Use & configure Wine with a default printer.
- Rewrite the software with Gambas.
- Rewrite the VB software as a PHP/MySql web application and use Firefox or Chromium for printing to a default printer.

Now I never used Wine or Gambas, but I can easily creare the web application.

I am kind of afraid that with the first 2 solutions I will have to spend a lot of time in configuration, test and acquire knowledge that I don't have. Also I read about many people having troubles with printers in Wine and Gambas.
And with the 3rd solution I am afraid that it will turn out to be not much professional/slow/problematic because it needs a working internet connection and everything will be online.

What do you think it will be the best approach?

Comment: you can run xp from a virtualbox inside ubuntu. Doesn't it help?

Comment: Ron, the user has a low-level knowledge, everything should be 1-click ready. I'm afraid that with emulators things will get too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolve this issue, a application web is the best solution, you don't need internet connection. You can develop a web application and put on the web server using LAMP or LEMP server of local way. Also, if you develop a application with Gambas you don't need Wine, this is need only if you try run de VB app in Linux.